# how to use && with grep in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I want to check if multiple lines in a file exist in bash.

so for that I use `grep -q` which works with only one line:

```
if grep -q string1 "/path/to/file";then
  echo 'exists'
else
  echo 'does not exist'
fi
```

I tried many things in various combinations, for example:

`if grep -q [ string1 ] && grep -q [ string2 ] "path/to/file";then`

I also tried it with `-E`:

`grep -E 'pattern1' filename | grep -E 'pattern2'`

but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `grep -q string_1 file && grep -q string_2 file`?

Comment: @iruvar Post it as an answer

Comment: this I tried as well but then the script never finishes

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner, that might be because you missed specifying the `file` after `string1`?

Comment: oh man, I feel so dumb, that works. But that means in bash it's not possible to write that simpler than that? like in other languages where you only have `if (cond1 && cond2) .... `

Comment: Of *course* it's possible, but you need to think about the details of what your commands are actually doing. `grep -E 'pattern1' filename | grep -E 'pattern2'` is looking for the presence of individual lines that match both patterns, not checking whether there exists at least one line that matches each (without inspecting for intersection).

Comment: ...a proper way to read `grep -q string_1 && grep -q string_2 FILE` as pseudocode is *if (string_1 is found in stdin) && (string_2 is found in FILE)*. Of course, this means it needs to read all of stdin to determine whether the first half of that condition is true, which is why your original code hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since @iruvar hasn't posted his comment as answer, i'll put it here:

```
grep -q string_1 file && grep -q string_2 file
```

now, here is my contribution. is @anubhava's more computationally complex `awk` answer, which reads the file only once, any faster than @iruvar's simpler answer, which reads the file three times?

```
awk          11.730 s
grep && grep  0.258 s
```

no.

this surely will depend on the speed of the filesystem vs the cpu, and on how much caching goes on, but on my system, which is probably a typical B+/A- workstation, `grep kw1 file && grep kw2 file && grep kw3 file` is ~50x as fast as @anubhava's `awk` solution. this held true both on ssd and spindle raid. (details: test file was 5,000,000 lines, 160M, and had `kw1` on the first line, `kw2` on the 2.5 millionth, and `kw3` on the 5 millionth.)

some easy optimization is possible, for example, if you can solve your problem by matching whole lines, do so (with `grep -x`); it's twice as fast in this case.

for many (e.g., >1,000) files, it is faster to use `grep -l` and `xargs`:

```
grep -l kw1 *.txt | xargs grep -l kw2 | xargs grep -q kw3
```

as opposed to a loop:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    grep -q kw1 $f && grep -q kw2 $f && grep -q kw3 $f
done
```

with the same test file, `grep -l | xargs grep` took 0.258 s, just like `grep && grep`. with two test files, it was still no faster than `grep && grep`. with 2000 test files of 5,000 lines each, none of which contained any matches, `grep -l | xargs grep` was ~10x as faster as `grep && grep`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than running multiple `grep` commands you can use this `gnu-awk` command to assert presence of multiple strings in a file:

```
awk -v RS='\\Z' '/string1/ && /string2/ && /string3/{e=1} END{exit !e}' file &&
echo 'exists' || echo 'does not exist'
```

- `RS=\Z` will make awk read all the input in a single record separator
- Using `&&` between multiple search terms will make sure all the search words exist in input file
- This will print `exists` only if all 3 search terms exists in the input file.

Comment: Seems a bit memory-inefficient to do the single-record thing. Is there a cause for it here? (I read the question, via "multiple lines [...] exist", to specify the individual patterns will match separate lines).

Comment: We are trying to find patterns across different lines. I haven't done benchmarking but IMO it will be more efficient than `grep -q string1 file && grep -q string2 file && grep -q string3 file`

Comment: I definitely agree that this is more IO-efficient than multiple greps, I just don't see why you aren't having your awk code apply the patterns line-by-line, setting a flag whenever any pattern is matched (perhaps exiting early as soon as both are), and thus relax the memory requirements when operating on large inputs.

Comment: Patterns can exist anywhere even on the last line so we cannot exit with failure earlier. We can actually do `exit 0` as soon as all the search terms have been matched.

Comment: Yes, exit 0 on matching all terms is what I suggested.

Comment: [The thing with awk is that `END` block always executes](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html) so even if I do: `awk -v RS='\\Z' '/123/ && /uvw/ && /foobar/{e=1; exit 0} END{exit !e}' file` It will still execute `END` block and we cannot remove `END` block for returning failure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113769/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-anubhava).

Comment: As a generic and more memory efficient solution one can use: `awk -v words='kw1;kw2;kw3' 'BEGIN{n=split(words, w, /;/); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) p[w[i]]} {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) if (w[i] in p && $0 ~ w[i]) delete p[w[i]]; if (length(p)==0) {e=1; exit 0}} END{exit !e}' file`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
if grep -q 'string1' /path/to/file; then
    if grep -q 'string2' /path/to/file; then
        echo exists
     else
        echo 'does not exist'
 else
     echo 'does not exist'
 fi
```

Or:

```
grep -q 'string1' /path/to/file &&
grep -q 'string2' /path/to/file &&
echo exists ||
echo 'does not exist'
```

Comment: I think he needs all patterns to exist within the file to succeed

Comment: This is OR, not AND.

Comment: `a && b && c || d` is not a terser way to write for `if a && b; then c; else d; fi`. What if stdout is closed and `echo exists` fails? (You go on to then also try to echo "does not exist", even though the content was in fact found).

Comment: the first solution I had in mind too, but then you have `echo 'does not exist'` twice in the code

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ambiguities in your question, but assuming you want pattern_1 and pattern_2 to exist in a file (not on the same line) then you can do this.

```
for file in *; do
  egrep -q pattern_1 $file && egrep -q pattern_2 $file && echo $file
done
```

Comment: Needs more quotes. `"$file"`, not `$file`, or this will fail badly with filenames with spaces.

Comment: It'll also behave bizarrely if you have, say, a file created with `touch '*.txt'` -- it'll grep all text files, and list all text files, rather than just that one alone when it comes up. Quotes are your friend.

Answer (score 1):

With `grep -p` you can match multiply patterns in the same line:

```
grep -P '(?=.*string1)(?=.*string2)' file
```

The above will print lines that matches `string1` and `string2`.

`(?=...)` is a [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) which matches a pattern without making it a part of the match.

And `-z` will slurp the whole file:

```
% seq 1 100 | grep -qzP '(?=.*1)(?=.*5)'; echo $?
0
% seq 1 100 | grep -qzP '(?=.*1)(?=.*a)'; echo $?
1
```

Comment: I think you could just use `grep -e 'pattern1' -e 'pattern2'`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Wouldn't that do a logical OR? I think OP wants logical AND

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right and it looks like he wants AND. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "-q" to search using grep

```
if  grep -q string1 "/path/to/file" &&  grep -q string2 "/path/to/file";then
      echo 'exists'
    else
      echo 'does not exist'
    fi
```

Comment: That's an OR; the question asks for an AND (with the patterns expected to match on different lines from each other).

Comment: `||` is still OR -- whereas if you modified it to be `&&`, your answer would be preceded by that by Jahid.

Comment: my mistake  
Updated now, use " && "